# Unrecoverable error when upgrading to civicrm-5.41.0

Tags: upgrade

I have a script to upgrade my civicrm configuration running under Drupal 7:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=$(basename "$0")

BIN="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
DRUPALROOT="/usr/share/drupal"
DOWNLOADDIR="$HOME/Downloads"
USER="www-data"

PKG=$(find "$DOWNLOADDIR" -name 'civicrm-*-drupal.tar.gz' | sort -rV | head -n1)

read -r -p "$CMD: Installing $(basename "$PKG") (y/n)? " answer
if [ "$answer" != "y" ] ; then
  exit 1
fi

error () {
  [ -n "$1" ] && echo "$CMD: $1"
  echo "$CMD: Aborted"
  exit 1
}

cd "$DRUPALROOT" 2>/dev/null || error "No such directory: $DRUPALROOT"
# sudo true is used to ask the password from the user 
# before putting the website into maintenance mode
sudo true  || error "Authentication failed"

drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 1             || exit 4

sudo -u "$USER" "$BIN"/drush cache-clear all      || exit 5
( cd sites/all/modules 2>/dev/null || 
    error "No such directory: $DRUPALROOT/sites/all/modules"  
  sudo mv civicrm civicrm.bak                     || exit 6
  sudo -u "$USER" tar -xzf "$PKG" ||
    error "Couldn't extract from archive $PKG"
  sudo rm -rf civicrm.bak                         || exit 8
) 
sudo -u "$USER" "$BIN"/drush civicrm-upgrade-db   || exit 9

drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 0             || exit 10

sudo -u "$USER" "$BIN"/drush cache-clear all      || exit 11
```

The command `drush vset --exact maintenance_mode 1` gave as output:

```
maintenance_mode was set to 1.                                       [success]
```

Next command `sudo -u "$USER" "$BIN"/drush cache-clear all` was also successful:

```
'all' cache was cleared.                                             [success]
```

But then I got an unrecoverable error message when the `drush` command was executed:

```
WD php: Error: Class 'CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base' not found [error]
in require_once() (line 29 of
/usr/share/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/dataprocessor/CRM/DataprocessorSearch/Form/Search/Custom/DataprocessorSmartGroupIntegration.php).
Error: Class &#039;CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base&#039; not found in require_once() (line 29 of /usr/share/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/dataprocessor/CRM/DataprocessorSearch/Form/Search/Custom/DataprocessorSmartGroupIntegration.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
```

I never had problems until today, and that is the reason why the processing of errors is still not gracefully. the statements `exit 4` and following should be replaced by a call to the function `error ()`, which is not yet implemented.

I also discovered that the backup directory `civicrm.bak` was also distroyed after the failed installation, which is an ugly bug of my script.

I have backups made with `backup_migrate` but since my webinterface is down, I don't know how to recover from the command line.

I am here to ask for any pointer to start fixing this mess.

Comment: First target has been reached: I could downgrade to civicrm 5.40.1 and the website is up and running again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2812.

There is a temporary quick-fix at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21347/files